# why does a .ui-widget match .ui-widget .ui-widget

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

I'm experimenting with jquery-ui and looking at and cloning some examples. In one example (autocomplete's combobox) I see an anchor (a) element with class ui-widget which gets matched against `.ui-widget .ui-widget { css: stuf}` in the included css file.

I cloned more or less this example but my version of `a.ui-widget` matches `.ui-widget { other-css: stuff}` (as I would expect)

What would make the first example match the double entry in the css file and my cloning single entry.

I don't see any other relevant differences css entries are the same.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What exactly is this element, which rules does it match and which rules does it not match? You'll want to list out all the relevant CSS rules and point to which ones match and which don't.

Comment: I think I forgot that the double .ui-widget means a parent and child element both have a .ui-widget class (which I understood from you erased answer. thanks!). For some reason the repetition prevented me from seeing parent child relation.

Answer (score 1):

`.ui-widget` as a selector is more general (or less specific): it will match *any* element so long as the element has that class. A `.ui-widget` is still a `.ui-widget`, whether or not it is contained within *some other* `.ui-widget` element, so it will still match the `.ui-widget` selector.

If the rules with the `.ui-widget` selector are *overriding* the same rules declared with the selector `.ui-widget .ui-widget` for the same element, then something is wrong, since the latter is more specific and so should take precedence. But that doesn't stop both selectors from matching the same element since you're basically looking for the same class.